# Base href not working on IE - alternative?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, include, href, radix

So after doing a lot of research I found base href, and I decided I should use it to build my website. After finishing I noticed that it was working on every browser(latest version): Chrome/Firefox/Opera except IE 9.

My site is built like that, on localhost:

```
<base href="/My_Site/" />
```

Then I use php include to add elements found on root directory and not in the same folder with current page:

```
<?php include "../header.php"?>
```

Now since I will be uploading this to the web, I suppose base href will be changed from My_Site to http://mysite.com/ and I wanted to know if everything will be working after doing so? What do I have to do to make it work on IE too?

Comment: i bet html base href wont affect including php files in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use closer tag for base in IE, other browsers require only self-close.
So it should be:

```
<base href="/My_Site/" /><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
```

(Assuming that href value is correct)

Comment: Still not working locally, will try on web now. EDIT: Uploaded on a free host, now it works for IE.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the full path.

Example:

```
<base href="<?="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/"?>My_Site/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, my guess is that there is some character, outside any tags, before the  tag. Consider this:

```
<base href="http://domain.net/qu/en/" />
<a href="sample">Sample Link</a>
```