# Which versions of IE require the base tag close bugfix?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Which versions of IE are susceptible to the base tag closing bug?

There is a bug in IE where it needs the base tag to be closed, ([eg, see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818827/base-href-not-working-on-ie-alternative)) In most other browsers the [base tag is left unclosed in HTML (xhtml is another matter)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp). The workaround is to use selective comments, something like the following:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com"><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->
```

But I'd prefer to limit this to the versions of IE that need it, that is, something like this:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com"><!--[if lte IE 9]></base><![endif]-->
```

But I can't find a reference to whether this was fixed in IE 10 (or 11 or 9).

Edit:
Just to clarify, according to the [W3C page on the base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) , in HTML (including HTML5, but not XHTML), the tag is *not closed at all*, not even self closing.

Comment: I believe it was just IE6 that had the bug but I can't find any proof of this. I expect modern browsers are happy for it to be self-closed.

Comment: I found [this blog post](http://ruthsarian.wordpress.com/2006/01/31/ie-base-tag-bug) in which the author links to [a related Drupal.org thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/44934#comment-88921), which says it was observed in IE6. There doesn't appear to be any information on any other versions, but that might simply be due to the fact that at the time the thread was posted (early 2006), *IE6 was the latest version*.

Comment: I’d prefer not to be using `base` at all in the first place … I have _never_ really needed that thing before, and in general I think it creates more issues than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is fixed in IE 7..

Before IE-7 you can put base tag anywhere in the page, but from IE7 it will only consider if the base tag in the head, and ignore all others.

IE-7 and further dont required base tag to be closed.

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can self-close that tag.

Comment: I don't see any part of that documentation that specifically refers to the `</base>` end tag, just the use of the `base` element in general.

Comment: Check examples at the end of page, you can able to see the example shown does not include the closing of tags.

Comment: Hi Malhar, thanks for the reference, but in the examples on that page the tag is self-closed. See my edits to the original question. I think the bug fixed from IE7 mentioned is only to do with the base tag having to be in the head.